# How to save multiple masks as a preset for use on different clips in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere, adobe, effects, mask, presets

I am working in Adobe Premiere. I am building a kaleidoscope effect that I would like to save as a preset to apply to other clips.

To build the kaliedoscope I have stacked a number of copies of the original clip, and to each of these copies i have added a small diamond shaped mask. Each copy has a unique position for the mask starting from the center and moving the mask outward to create the kaliedscope according to a diamond shaped grid.

This is quite time consuming to build and I would like reuse this effect throughout a video, and again in future.

How can I save this collection of masks as a preset to be applied to different clips by dragging and dropping?

So far I have only worked out saving all the individual masks (Opacity) and locations (Motion) as individual presets. Then each time manually making the copies of the new clip and applying those effects settings to each clip. There are more than 20 masks and this is still quite tedious. Is it possible to save all of those masks as one preset, or in a preset bin, or as a layer, to be automatically applied to a new clip as a nested sequence? How would you go about doing this?

Sincere thanks for your help.

I have attached a screenshot of my workspace so you can see the effect build so far. The grid is only there for reference to position each mask.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think to create a Preset in Premier Pro you have to add a few factors to it like effects
OK ?
Because you can't make Preset through musks
You make all the changes and add a separate effect to it, but set the keyframe to zero and do the factors according to the tutorial below.

Good luck

Comment: Hi Thanks Amer. I am aware how to build presets from effects, but I was asking if this is possible to bundle separate presets into one, specifically position of masks in this case. As you say you can't really make presets through masks which I guess is the answer. What I have done, is save all 20 masks each as separate presets (Location & Opacity effects), put them in a new Preset Bin. Then when I want to use the effect, I have to make 20 copies, and drag each mask onto each iteration of the clip, and then nest them. It works, just a little time consuming.

Comment: Hi, I thought maybe this could be done this way
With the explanation you gave, I think you should do the same as before, and unfortunately you may not be able to do that right now.
Forgive me again. Good luck